# DB Schema Taxonomy for species : conditional joins or redesign?

Tags: sql-server

I need some advice to design a DB Schema. I am working on a project where I need to classify species.

All species belong to a gender, a family, an order, a class, a branch and finaly a kingdom.

But some of them have a subBranch between class and branch. I first gave the species entity a FK pointing to each single taxonomy.

Then I thought about only giving the species entity the "gender FK" and go all the way up from there to get its full taxonomy. It seemed to work but I realised I could not retreive the subBranch for species concerned by it.

[image]

In the class entity I have two FK, one for subBranch and one for branch. Depending on the species, the branchId FK exists in the class entity (and then the subBranch FK is null) leading to Branch and then Kingdom. Or the subBranch FK exists and leads to the SubBranch then from there to Branch and finally kindgom.

In SQL, I have something like this for the species view (I commented in english where I am stuck):

```
 SELECT 
  S.*,
  G.LatinName as 'GenderLatinName',
  G.Name as 'GenderName',
  F.LatinName as 'FamilyLatinName',
  F.Name as 'FamilyName',
  O.LatinName as 'OrderLatinName',
  O.Name as 'OrderName',
  C.LatinName as 'ClassLatinName',
  C.Name as 'ClassName',
  Sb.LatinName as 'SubBranchLatinName',
  Sb.Name as 'SubBranchName',
  B.LatinName as 'BranchLatinName',
  B.Name as 'BranchName',
  K.LatinName as 'KingdomLatinName',
  K.Name as 'KingdomName'

  from Species S
    join Gender G on G.Id = S.GenderId
    join Family F on F.Id = G.FamilyId
    join [Order] O on O.Id = F.OrderId
    join Class C on C.Id = O.ClassId

    --if class entity has an existing SubBranchId then join SubBranch to it and then the Branch to the SubBranch

    --  if C.SubBranchId is not null
    --      then join SubBranch on Sb.BranchId on C.BranchId
    --      then join Branch on B.Id on Sb.BranchId

    --if class entity has no SubBranchId then straightaway join Branch to it

    --  else 
    --      join Branch on B.Id on C.BranchId

    join Branch B on B.Id = C.BranchId
    join Kingdom K on K.Id = B.KingdomId
```

I have seen some questions on conditional joins but I could not get it work. I thought about the UNION ALL but the number of columns vary between the two queries as one has an additional field.

Perhaps the schema design needs to be changed.

How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is generally fine, apart from 2 rather minor notes:

1. In taxonomy, it's usually called "Genus", not "Gender";
2. I strongly suggest to come up with some other name for the `Order` table. Trust me, if you will have to write any amount of code worth mentioning against a schema like that, you'll curse the day you chose the table name to be the same as this particular reserved keyword. `Orders`, `Order_`, `OrderT` (from "Taxonomy") - anything will do.

As such, the query should be quite simple:

```
select s.*,
    -- Other columns
    isnull(sb.LatinName, '(No sub-branch)') as [SubBranchLatinName],
    -- The rest of stuff
from Species S
    inner join Genus G on G.Id = S.GenusId
    inner join Family F on F.Id = G.FamilyId
    inner join OrderT O on O.Id = F.OrderId
    inner join Class C on C.Id = O.ClassId
    inner join Branch B on B.Id = C.BranchId
    left join dbo.SubBranch sb on sb.BranchId = b.Id and sb.Id = c.SubBranchId
    inner join Kingdom K on K.Id = B.KingdomId
```

Left join allows you to bring in the table which might contain no rows that match the condition, without losing these rows in the final output.

Comment: thanks for the advice.. indeed names like Order and other reserved keywords needs to be put like this [Order]..that's annoying

Comment: as for the left join, I am not loosing the rows when there is no link with the SubBranch entity but that query makes me lose the record that actually have a link with the subBranch..

Comment: Missing the record? Make sure that the `BranchId` field for this particular species has the same value in both `SubBranch` and `Class` tables (and of course `KingdomId` should exist and point to a valid record). Anything else.. no, it's too simple a case to miss anything here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that having a star schema i.e. SPECIES table contain FKs to each taxonomy table would be faster for selects. This will also remove complications of conditional joins and any other logical "anomalies".

If you want to stick with a chain, then there are two ways:

1. Conditional join:

Example Below

```
  from Species S
    join Gender G on G.Id = S.GenderId
    join Family F on F.Id = G.FamilyId
    join [Order] O on O.Id = F.OrderId
    join Class C on C.Id = O.ClassId
    LEFT JOIN SubBranch AS SB ON .....
    INNER JOIN Branch AS B ON SB.BranchID = B.Id OR C.BranchID = B.Id
```

This will be slow.

`UNION ALL` approach would probably be faster. To work around number of columns differences, you will need to add `NULL` and/or empty string constants in place of SubBranch columns for the query without SubBranch.

2. Another way is to add a dummy sub branch records for classes without a sub branch. This way there is always a record in SubBranch table, and you do not need conditional joins. I recommend this solution.